# Laravel looks for a table that doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to PHP. I made a table called `tbl_users` but for some reasons that i cant understand laravel is trying some other table name called `users`.

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'raydb.users' doesn't exist`

my migration code look like this and its the same in the seeder. the usage of just `users` is thrown nowhere.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tbl_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Name');
        $table->string('Email')->unique();
        $table->string('Password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

i made a new controller that is trying to call the table it looks like this

```
function login(Request $req){
    return User::where(['email'=>$req->email])->first();
}
```

i cant really find some other place the table or SQL is called...
i see the table `tbl_Users` in MySQL and everything inside with the proper login name password etc. i dont understand where laravel get the calling of a table called `users`

Comment: You should name your tables the way Laravel expects you to. The `User` model will look for the `users` table by default. While you can override this, it's only really a good idea if you're trying to work with pre-existing table structures you can't change. The `tbl_users` naming convention is very 1990s.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674309/laravel-assumes-the-database-table-is-the-plural-form-of-the-model-name

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384481/how-does-eloquent-recognize-tables

Comment: I started ASP 2 months ago. i started PHP 1 week ago. no need for elitjerk attitude. If i ever gonna learn this i have to ask questions that might be obvious for someone who done this for years.  Had no idea the code is updating so drastic from each time they make changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel uses conventions to make your life easier. One of those conventions is that Laravel assumes that your table names are the plural of your model names. You should read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names) for more information.

You're using a model called `User` so behind the scenes Laravel is using it's convention and looking for a table called `users` in your database. If you want to override the name of the table a model is associated with, you need to specify the table name on your model.

```
class User extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'tbl_users';
}
```

Ideally though, unless you have a specific reason not to do so it is advisable to stick to the Laravel table naming convention. It will make your life and others lives easier in the long run.